# Append values from textscan into cell array literately in a loop

Tags: matlab

Currently I have a txt file with data as shown below:

```
A11
Temperature=20 Weight=120 Speed=65
B13
Temperature=21 Weight=121 Speed=63
F24
Temperature=18 Weight=117 Speed=78
D43
Temperature=16 Weight=151 Speed=42
C32
Temperature=15 Weight=101 Speed=51
```

I would like to read the value into a cell array and convert it as matrix.
Below is my code:

```
% At first I read the data into a 1 column array

fid=fopen('file.txt');
tline = fgetl(fid);
tlines = cell(0,1);
while ischar(tline)
    tlines{end+1,1} = tline;
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);

% Then I check the size of the cell array

CellSize = size(tlines);
DataSize = CellSize(1,1);

% At last I setup a loop and literately read and input the values

Data = cell(0,3);
for i = 1:DataSize  
    Data{end+1,3} = textscan(tlines{i,1},'Temperature=%f Weight=%f Speed=%f');   
end
```

However, I got 10x3 empty cell array.

```
[]  []  *1x3cell*
[]  []  *1x3cell*
[]  []  *1x3cell*
[]  []  *1x3cell*
[]  []  *1x3cell*
[]  []  *1x3cell*
[]  []  *1x3cell*
[]  []  *1x3cell*
[]  []  *1x3cell*
[]  []  *1x3cell*
```

I know the problem comes from the input of textscan value into the cell array. Can you help me fix the problem? Also how can I toss the empty value if the data doesn't contain the specific format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mistake you made, was to index the content of `Data` using `{}`, and not the cells using `()`, see the [help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).

I modified the last part of your script:

```
% At last I setup a loop and literately read and input the values

Data = cell(DataSize, 3);
for i = 1:DataSize  
    Data(i, :) = textscan(tlines{i}, 'Temperature=%f Weight=%f Speed=%f')  
end
```

Gives the following output:

```
Data =
{
  [1,1] = [](0x1)
  [2,1] =  20
  [3,1] = [](0x1)
  [4,1] =  21
  [5,1] = [](0x1)
  [6,1] =  18
  [7,1] = [](0x1)
  [8,1] =  16
  [9,1] = [](0x1)
  [10,1] =  15
  [1,2] = [](0x1)
  [2,2] =  120
  [3,2] = [](0x1)
  [4,2] =  121
  [5,2] = [](0x1)
  [6,2] =  117
  [7,2] = [](0x1)
  [8,2] =  151
  [9,2] = [](0x1)
  [10,2] =  101
  [1,3] = [](0x1)
  [2,3] =  65
  [3,3] = [](0x1)
  [4,3] =  63
  [5,3] = [](0x1)
  [6,3] =  78
  [7,3] = [](0x1)
  [8,3] =  42
  [9,3] = [](0x1)
  [10,3] =  51
}
```

Afterwards you could do:

```
% Clean up.
for i = DataSize:-1:1
  if (isempty([Data{i, :}]))
    Data(i, :) = [];
  end
end
```

So that your output looks like this:

```
Data =
{
  [1,1] =  20
  [2,1] =  21
  [3,1] =  18
  [4,1] =  16
  [5,1] =  15
  [1,2] =  120
  [2,2] =  121
  [3,2] =  117
  [4,2] =  151
  [5,2] =  101
  [1,3] =  65
  [2,3] =  63
  [3,3] =  78
  [4,3] =  42
  [5,3] =  51
}
```

Also, please don't do things like `Data{end+1,3}`, if the size is known in advance. I also modified this accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the header/name, this is not terribly elegant, but it will work:

```
fin = 'yourfilename.txt';
fid = fopen(fin);
stuff = textscan(fid, '%s');
fclose(fid);
stuff = stuff{:};
stuff = strrep(stuff, 'Temperature=', '');
stuff = strrep(stuff, 'Weight=', '');
stuff = strrep(stuff, 'Speed=', '');
len = length(stuff) / 4;
name = cell(1,len);
temp = NaN(1,len);
wt = NaN(1,len);
speed = NaN(1,len);
counter = 0;
for ii = 1:len
    name(ii) = stuff(ii + counter);
    temp(ii) = str2double(stuff(ii + counter +1));
    wt(ii) = str2double(stuff(ii + counter +2));
    speed(ii) = str2double(stuff(ii + counter +3));
    counter = counter + 3;
end
name = cell2table(name', 'VariableNames', {'Name'});
temp = array2table(temp', 'VariableNames', {'Temperture'});
wt = array2table(wt', 'VariableNames', {'Weight'});
speed = array2table(speed', 'VariableNames', {'Speed'});
data = [name temp wt speed];
```